# Latitude and Longitude Java

Tags: java, database, latitude-longitude

I want to write a simple program in Java that given to cities it will calculate the distance between them from there latitude and longitude.

But I can't find anywhere on the internet a database of cities in the world and their lat and longs. The closest I found was: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite, but this is just America.

Does anyone know somewhere where I can find this data, or an alternative way to do it if this data can't be found??

The reason I'm writing this program is just to learn about processing data and using and storing objects in Java - nut I can't find any data to process!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latitude Longitude Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572/latitude-longitude-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739) is called  **geocoding**.

You can either code a known list of place name/lat-lons into your app, read them in at runtime and search through them when required, or you can use an online Geocoding service such as this  [Google Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful and clear, 
I've literally spent hours on Google, and your answer summarised what I was looking for really well - THANKS!!

Comment: @user2076554 : u r wc

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenStreeMap's API, Nominatim, and a query like this (Assuming that XMLReader is a simple XML parser.):

```
try {
        URL osm = new URL("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&q=" + city.replaceAll(" ","+"));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) osm.openConnection();
        XMLReader xml = new XMLReader(connection.getInputStream());
        connection.disconnect();

        lat = xml.getLat();
        lon = xml.getLon();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Here is an [example](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&q=London) of the query for London.